# How old are these four characters supposed to be?

Tags: plot-explanation, sneaky-pete

In [*Sneaky Pete*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5011816/), Tex (played by [M. Emmet Walsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Emmet_Walsh), born 22 March 1935) is father of

Audrey Bernhardt (played by [Margo Martindale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margo_Martindale), born 18 July 1951) who is mother of

Maggie Murphy (played by [Jane Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Adams_(actress,_born_1965)), born 1 April 1965) who is mother of

Pete Murphy (played by [Ethan Embry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethan_Embry), born 13 June 1978).

Using the actors' ages rather than the characters' ages, I guess it's not impossible for a male to have a child at age 16 or for a female to have a child at age 13, but it does somewhat beggar belief.

So, how old are the above four characters supposed to be?

(I'm not sure but I believe Lila Bowman, another daughter of Audrey, might be even older than Maggie. If so, Audrey would've been even younger when she had her first child.)

(Also, in the show, Maggie Murphy is mistakenly believed to be the mother of Marius Josipović, played by [Giovanni Ribisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Ribisi), born December 17, 1974. The age difference between Jane Adams and Ribisi is about 9 years and 8 months.)

Comment: I think the words you're looking for are "crap casting"